# Find a value in a array with varible

Tags: arrays, excel

In Excel I have an array named "level" in column 3 that is as follows
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, BR, 7, 8, 9, 10, BR, 11, 12, 13, 14, BR, 15, 16, 17, 18, BR, 19, 20.....
There is a variable in C1 which is the starting point to search the array.

What I would like to be able to do is enter the variable in C1, as an example say 8 and get the number prior to the "BR" in this case 10.
or
1-6 should give me the value of 6, 7-10 a value of 10, 11-14 a value of 14 and so on.

With some help I came up with

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("BR", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(C1,level, 0), 3) & ":" & ADDRESS(ROWS(level), 3)), 0)+MATCH(C1,level, 0)-2, 3))
```

It works fine except for when the number following the "BR" are the variable.
In which case it gives the number above the previous "BR"
*Example 11  gives 10*

Also the locations of the "BR" in the array may change.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's yet another alternative.

```
=INDEX(level,MATCH("BR",(OFFSET(INDEX(level,1),MATCH(C1,level,0),0,ROWS(level)-MATCH(C1,level,0))),0)+MATCH(C1,level,0)-1)
```

Comment: that works Perfect, as well, could you add an offset to show the value in row b?

Comment: Glad it worked OK. Wasn't sure what you meant in your comment though?

Comment: Is there a way to use  roughly the same code but have the answear be in the same row as "BR"  in colomn B? In the code I was using I would just change the row from 3 to 2.

Comment: The answer can be anywhere, but it just looks in whichever column 'level' applies to. I won't be able to look further at this till tomorrow as it's quite late here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I came up with a fix.  I did  "=offset (the formula)1,-1)" works just fine.  Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

Try this **array-entered** formula.  Enter the formula by holding down `ctrl-shift` while hitting `enter`.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula in the formula bar

```
=INDEX(Level,-1+MATCH(TRUE,(Level="BR")*ROW(Level)>MATCH($C$1,Level,0),0))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help.  This is giving me #NAME?

Comment: @ahhhh Did you copy/paste the formula?  Check for typos.  The other possibility is that you do not have Level defined as a Named Range on the proper worksheet, as would seem to be the case in your example.

Comment: Sorry, giving me #N/A

Comment: @ahhhh That is because you did not enter it with `ctrl+shift+enter` as I wrote in my Answer!  When entered correctly, it works as you seem to want on your sample data worksheet.

Comment: As did I on your sample workbook. It should work in any cell that is not part of "level".  When you select F5, and examine the formula bar, do you see the braces around the formula?

Comment: @ahhhh Glad to help.  If you could mark my response as the answer, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Probably. You can always use evaluate. But I would do it differently

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided worked fine in my excel, however, the 3rd column contains the C1 cell you mention, maybe that's why messes it up in your file. Are you sure the cell you use to enter the searched value does not interfere with your definition of level ?

Can you make your table accessible?

Comment: Hello, thank for your help. C1 is not in the range (it was in an earlier version but took it out of the named range) here is the sheet.  It works fine except for 7, 11, 14, and 19 https://app.box.com/s/6udnxtgkijwmy0j5r87giz7mog5xkvjm

Comment: OK the formula you use only work if Level start on line 1. To make it work, the easy way it to switch all occurences off address :  replace all ADDRESS(Something,3) by ADDRESS(Something+1,3). It's not good looking but it will work.